# How to verify if user is logged in?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `CodeIgniter` framework for `PHP`. There are some pages that are exclusively for Admin and they are located in `Admin/*`. When the user logs in, i store some value in session as a flag and verify it in my controller to test whether the user is logged or not. I wrote the code to check session in every method in my controller. But, then I realized i didn't want to write the same line of code in each and every method since many issues are created from maintainability point of view. Then i decided to create a exclusive Controller which will load only Admin views and thus in it's constructor i check the session value. Is there any other method apart from this approach. Am i doing it right? Or any other secure mechanism is available in `CodeIgniter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've taken one of the best approaches (my opinion), just make the other admin controllers extend from that controller so you can have specialized controllers (admin blog, admin gallery etc). If you need help, I'll gladly help you.

Comment: Hey Flakron, I appreciate more help/advice on with. Specifically on how to set the controller up in the first place. And then how to get the other controller to extend it whilst extending CI_controller at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in your constructor method something like this,

```
function __construct {
    parent::construct();
    /* Do you login check here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
class Admin extends Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->is_logged_in();
 }

 function is_logged_in()
 {

   $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
   if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
   {
     redirect('login');
   }
 }
```